# Clearing Search Results Input Box

Tags: search

When a search results page is displayed, by default the search input box shows the text searched for. Is there a way to change that so that it is blank by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the search box using jQuery.

The code below can be added to your results page in a Content Editor Web Part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('.s4-searchbox-QueryPrompt').val(""); 
    });
</script>
```

Note the class name used in the selector `$('.s4-searchbox-QueryPrompt')` is for SharePoint 2010 and may differ between versions. You can use FireBug or a similar page inspecting tool to find the class.

If you need help adding jQuery to SharePoint, see [this article](http://www.threewill.com/adding-jquery-to-sharepoint/) for various ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The Search Result Webpart works in a way that it uses url parameters (something like "?k=test" to search for "test". So when you enter "test" into your search input box and hit enter it adds the url parameter.

An input box works in a way that it always shows the url parameter aswell.

So the short answer is: No
Long answer: You can't modify the default webpart to do what you're looking for, you would have to replace the search input box by a custom webpart.
Possible option: Maybe you could hide the search string using javascript/css, but I'm not sure if you would be able to search for other words after that.